# How to make notifications when user open new tab or go to another tab?

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on a project that includes a test users must complete. Once the test has been started, I don't want participants to be able to open other sites or tabs. When they do open a new tab, I want to show an alert which will prompt them if they are sure they would like to open a new tab, thus completing the test.

I read about `Window.focus` and `onbeforeunload`, but `onbeforeunload` works only when you are closing tab and focus didn't work as I expected.

I wrote the whole project in Django but I think I should have used JS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. You should mention what you have tried and show your code for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,
Hopefully it works fine!

**onblur** is the funtion, when you will loose your focus on current tab, then this function will works.!

```
window.onblur = function () {
    // do some stuff after tab was changed e.g.
    alert('You switched the tab');
}
```

Comment: If it works fine, please upvote to answer and accept it.!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the browser. Your tab does not have access to information from other tabs, or events other than what happens on your page.

However, it is possible to make sure the mouse does not leave the screen. If you are using jQuery you can use

```
$(document).mouseleave(function () {
    console.log('out');
});
```